# Is a policy $\pi(s)$ on Markov decision process a random variable?

Tags: probability, markov-process, reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

Citing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process):

> The goal in a Markov decision process is to find a good "policy" for
> the decision maker: a function $\pi$  that specifies the action
> $\pi(s)$ that the decision maker will choose when in state $s$.   Once
> a Markov decision process is combined with a policy in this way, this
> fixes the action for each state and the resulting combination behaves
> like a Markov chain (since the action chosen in state $s$ is
> completely determined by $\pi(s)$ and $\Pr(s_{t+1}=s'\mid
> > s_{t}=s,a_{t}=a)$  $\Pr(s_{t+1}=s'\mid s_{t}=s,a_{t}=a)$   reduces to
> $Pr(s_{t+1}=s'\mid s_{t}=s)$ $Pr(s_{t+1}=s'\mid s_{t}=s)$, a Markov
> transition matrix).

A policy that maximizes the function above is called an optimal policy and is usually denoted $\pi^*$. A particular MDP may have multiple distinct optimal policies. Because of the Markov property, it can be shown that the optimal policy is a function of the current state, as assumed above.

Can the policy be considered a random variable?

Comment: The answer is in the question: "the optimal policy is a function of the current state".

Comment: A function of a random variable is a random variable?

Answer (score 2):

The policy is a function you define to act in an environment, it's not a random variable.